# How to configure nodeclipse for auto completion?

Tags: eclipse, node.js

I have just installed this eclipse plugin. But I found it can neither show a list of functions when typing '.', nor use templates like 'if...else...'.

Answer (score 1):

Read http://www.nodeclipse.org/ carefully

> #### Features
>
> - Creating default structure for New Node
>     Project and New Node Source File
> - Generating Express project
>     with Wizard
> - JavaScript Syntax highlighting
> - Bracket
>     matching and marking selection occurences with background color
> - Content Assistant within one file
> - Go to definition with
>     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click when [JSDoc is
>     used](http://usejsdoc.org/)
> - Refactoring within one file
>     (<kbd>Alt+Shift+R</kbd>)
> - JSON files highlight and
>     validation
> - NPM support
> - Debugging - Breakpoint,
>     Trace, Variables, Expressions, etc... via Eclipse debugger plugin for
>     V8
> - Setting project properties for JSHint-Eclipse
>     automatically;        [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) 
>           settings template
> - Passing arguments to Node application and Node.js,
>     specifying environment variables values to use
> - Running
>     CoffeeScript *.coffee files
> - Running *.js files with
>     PhantomJS, MongoDB Shell or Java 8 Nashorn
>
>   ```
>   jjs
>   ```
>
>   util
> - Bundled together with Markdown Editor, GitHub Flavored Markdown,
>     StartExplorer (for system explorer and shell),        RegEx, Icon Editor,
>     MongoDB, RestClient Tool      and other plugins (20+ in total, check
>     update site and       Nodeclispe Plugin
>     List)
> - Support for Eclipse Juno, Kepler, Luna M3

As of 0.7 completion work as standard JSDT functionality, that is

- for objects defined in the same class,
- for objects annotated with with JSDoc

If you want more, do it yourself with help from the other people.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that you install [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which uses the powerful JavaScript inference engine **tern.js**. You have a [node.js module](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Node.js-support) which provides node.js completion. As Nodeclipse editor is based on JSDT, you can use it with tern.